# Получать данные о местоположении чаще

Tags: java, android, kotlin, location

У меня имеется приложение, которое проверяет местоположение устройства и сохраняет его в файл.

```
if (playServicesAvailability == SUCCESS) {
        // Using Play Services API
        fusedLocationClient
            .lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                fusedLocationClient
                    .requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationRequest.create().apply {
                            interval = LOCATION_UPDATE_REQUEST_TIME
                            priority = PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                            smallestDisplacement = LOCATION_UPDATE_REQUEST_DISTANCE_FILTER
                        },
                        positionSupplier,
                        null
                    )
            }
    } else {
        // Using native API
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            LOCATION_UPDATE_REQUEST_TIME,
            LOCATION_UPDATE_REQUEST_DISTANCE_FILTER,
            positionSupplier
        )
```

При этом LOCATION_UPDATE_REQUEST_TIME = 0L и LOCATION_UPDATE_REQUEST_DISTANCE_FILTER = 0.
Однако, смартфон получает данные все равно раз в 10 секунд. Это связано с тем, что провайдер не отдаёт данные чаще? Или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее он их получает куда реже, чем в 10 секунд, а через апи выдаются интерполированные данные.

Comment: Что такого успеет сделать юзер за 10 сек., что вы не успеете заметить? При том что точность GPS +/-5м в идеальных условиях (посреди чистого поля и не меньше чем с тремя спутниками в зоне видимости).

Comment: @woesss Например, успеваю проехать поворот, И если захочу построить свой трек - момент поворота будет утерян и угол срежется.